# Is it grammatical to say of some potential meaning that it is "able to be said" or "trying to be said"?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, passive-voice, animacy

A recent commenter on a recent word-search question nominated a term as “an even better word for what is trying to be said.” This seems to me to attribute intention to something—a meaning—that is incapable of intention. I have also encountered this same fallacy, as it seems to me, with words such as *able* and *ability* followed by passive infinitive, in such a way as seemingly and absurdly to locate the ability in question in the patient rather than the agent. For some reason, passive constructions like *“capacity* to be [past participle],” and *“capability* of being [past participle],” which respectively locate the capacity and the capability in the patient, do not likewise bother me in the least:

> The <sup>235</sup>U nucleus has the unique capacity to be split by a neutron into <sup>89</sup>Kr, <sup>144</sup>Ba, and three neutrons that can in turn split further <sup>235</sup>U nuclei.

But I would never say or write that the nucleus *is able* or *has the ability* to be split.

To say that something “can be said” is unquestionably grammatical, and some instances of “able to be said” result from trying to put that into the future tense or conditional mood, as “will/would/could/should be able to be said.” To say that something is *sayable* is also unexceptionable: adjectives in *-able* or *-ible* normally tend to modify or be predicated of the patient.

A Google Books [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=able+to+be+said%2C+try+to+be+said%2C+trying+to+be+said&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) of “able to  be said,” “trying to  be said,” and  “try to  be said” shows very low but non-zero frequencies for the former two. A plain-vanilla Google search for “able to  be said” turns up (besides a few instances where a comma and right-hand quotation mark separate *be* from *said)* a surprisingly high proportion of results from Google books, and a surprisingly high proportion of results that are products of translation from other languages. (Also and less unexpectedly I found among the top results one that resulted from a transformation of “can be said” as discussed above.) Searching for “passive infinitive” in combination with “able” or “try” led me to some on-line grammatical resources, but the only one to discuss this particular problem was a page I had written for my students a few months back.

Comment: Do you perceive any difference between "*is able to X*" and "*is able **to be** Xed*"?

Comment: @Jim: Of course. It is the latter that I think almost always problematic in locating *ability* in the patient rather than in the agent (or to put that another way, in the done-to-rather than the doer).

Comment: I guess that's where we differ in interpretation.  In my mind "to be Xed" locates the ability with the doer not with X.  The *to be* turns the  action X done by the doer, to a state that can be assigned to X. If a package is ready **to be** picked up, the doer is me (the picker upper) not the package.  Saying that the package is able to be picked up says that the package is in a state such that pickup by someone is possible.  Likewise saying the package is unable to be picked up means there is something outside of the doer's control that would prevent him from picking it up.

Comment: @Jim +1 and thanks for the splendid example of the package ready to be picked up. (I was looking for such but drawing a blank.) But I see a big difference between attributing *readiness* to such an inanimate thing and attributing *ability* to it, and yes, I read *able to be picked up* as attributing ability to the package.

Comment: How do you feel about "_There is a package waiting at the front desk_"?

Comment: How do you feel about adjectives ending in *-[a,i]ble*? The package was transportable, the castle was defensible. I would translate these to mean: the package was able to be transported, the castle was able to be defended.

Comment: @Jim, I believe I addressed that in the question itself: “adjectives in *-able* or *-ible* normally tend to modify or be predicated of the patient”

Comment: @Neil, well, if the “package” were of the opposite sex and hot and just waiting to be picked up . . . but seriously, I think this is off topic.

Comment: What I meant was, I would translate, '*The nucleus is splittable*' as, '*The nucleus is able to be split.*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/able) has this to say about whether or not 'This is able to be said' is allowable:

> Usage Note:
>
> The construction *able to* takes an infinitive to show the subject's 
>   [referent's] ability to accomplish an action:
>
> *We were able to get a grant for the project.*
>   *The new submarine is able to dive twice as fast as the older model.*
>
> Some people think it should be avoided when the subject does not
>   have an ability, as in sentences with passive constructions involving
>   forms of the verb be:
>
> *The problem was able to be solved by using a new lab technique.*
>
> The reasoning here is that since the problem has no ability to
>   accomplish an action, it is not able to do anything, and therefore
>   able to should not be used.
>
> Presumably this ban would apply to similar words like *capable* and to
>   negative words like *unable* and *incapable*. In such cases one can 
>   usually avoid the problem by using can or could:
>
> *The problem could be solved....*
>
> Keep in mind, however, that passives with get ascribe a more active
>   role to their subjects, and here one can use *able to*:
>
> *He was able to get accepted by a top law school.*