# "unable to be" used with incorrect subject?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I see this phrase used a lot, and always thought it to be incorrect, but I see more and more people using it so I'd like to find out if I am wrong or not.

As an example the following sentences:

> The samples were unable to be collected.
>
> Sampling was unable to be performed.

It seems to me that the subject here are the samples or the sampling, therefore it is incorrect to use "unable to be" when they are describing an action that was to be done by someone else.

I would rather say one of the following

> We were unable to perform the sampling.
>
> We were unable to collect the samples.
>
> The samples could not be collected.
>
> The sampling could not be performed.

Do these last two have the same meaning?

Comment: I agree with you.  "Unable" implies that the subject has some agency.

Comment: Don't just assume that switching from ***unable to*** to ***can't / couldn't*** removes the implication of "agency". Native speakers would rarely say *This pen **can't write*** or *My car **couldn't start***, for example. Not that this is a "hard-and-fast" principle anyway, as you'll see if you look at some written instances of *[things / people] [**unable to be released**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unable+to+be+released%22)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it grammatical to say of some potential meaning that it is "able to be said" or "trying to be said"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182955/is-it-grammatical-to-say-of-some-potential-meaning-that-it-is-able-to-be-said)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see an inanimate object that is unable to do something as perfectly fine, if it is an object that normally perofms that action for example, like a car starting up vs not starting because there is somethign wrong with the car.  My qualm is with the statement that an object is unable to have someone act on it.  It is that someone that is unable to act on it.  For example "the samples were unable to be collected because the technicians had to prioritize a different task."  Would that sentence not be incorrect?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, that's a great thread that I didn't find despite me searching.  It seems like it is the same discussion.  Do you feel like there was a definitive answer to that thread?  Does it seem like it was still left a open with differing opinions?

Comment: Another example could be an item that is "unable to be located."  I understand the item might be difficult to find, but who is unable to complete the action here?  The item or the person/people looking for it?  Is that statement therefore incorrect?  Should it be "we were unable to locate the item"

Comment: The fact that a significant minority (24% vs 76%) of competent Anglophones (ie of the usage panel) disagree [here {again, AHD}](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/able), saying that 'The samples were able to be collected' say _is_ acceptable, proves that **there can be no definitive answer** ('right' / 'wrong').

Comment: Davide: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28which+is+unable+to+be%29%2B%28which+are+unable+to+be%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28which%20is%20unable%20to%20be%29%20%2B%20%28which%20are%20unable%20to%20be%29%3B%2Cc0) for *[thing/s] **which is/are unable to be** [acted upon / dealt with]*, which suggests that the "[conscious] agent" implications of the usage have become significantly more relaxed over recent decades.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, and FumbleFingers,  Thank you both.  I'm a little sad that there isn't a definitive answer as I really dislike the sound of that phrase :P.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like an ergative verb usage. The samples were to be [opened/thawed/moved/withdrawn](https://www.scribd.com/document/404128119/167196701-Unaccusative-and-Unergative-Verbs-List). *The samples were to be collected*. So where does the problem with *unable* come from? Why would *unable* not piggyback off the ergative verb's concept of agency? Same with unaccusative verbs, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Usage Panel decisions trump explanations of why constructions _should_ work.

Comment: *It seems to me that the subject here are the samples or the sampling, therefore it is incorrect to use "unable to be" when they are describing an action that was to be done by someone else.*

No. Both are passive sentences, and in the passive, it is not always necessary to mention the agent, especially if it can easily be implied or is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Passive voice has a great way of obscuring meaning...which is partly its point. It leaves ambiguous the actor or agent.

I did not do it. vs. It was not done.

So, considering the question, I believe most writers and speakers would consider these phrasings to be equivalent:

*The samples { weren't / couldn't be / weren't able to be } collected.*

Whether samples themselves have any influence on their ability to be collected, the condition of an object could affect its collectability.

*The samples were so degraded, they were unable to be collected.*

*The samples were so degraded, they were incapable of being collected.*

*The samples were so degraded, I was unable to collect them.*

The sentences really mean the same thing; the third just takes more responsibility.

I agree wholeheartedly with Mr. Ashworth's comment above, that it can't be established if one way is the only "right" phrase grammatically. You can argue whether it sounds wrong to give a quality of able-ness to a thing, but "unable to be collected" and "unable to sing opera" are not quite the same level of capability.